# Aurelia Webpack: how to load images

Tags: javascript, image, webpack, aurelia

I spent much time for realizing to load images. So, here is a note for others.

The following code generated HTTP 404 error and my background image did not appear.

```
my-css {
    background: url('../imgs/my-backgound.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fragment from the skeleton-typescript-webpack/webpack.config.js.
I should have a line for copying the imgs/my-background.png like this.

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  { from: 'static/favicon.ico', to: 'favicon.ico' },
  { from: 'imgs/my-background.png', to: 'imgs/my-background.png' },     // add this!
]),
```

EDIT: Since url-loader handles loading for png/jpg/gif files, I need to copy only files for url(xxx).

Answer (score 1):

For handling images, I would use the `url-loader` and the following in your rules section of `webpack.config.js`:

```
{ test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|cur)$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 8192 } },
```

The `url-loader` works very similarly to how the `file-loader` works, but using the supplied byte limit, your images will be converted to DataURL's instead of actual files and inline those into your generated bundles.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But, the line exists in the skeleton-webpack-typescript/webpack.config.js and does not work for background:url(...). I will update my answer to reflect that.